# android pre-allocate memory in the application

Tags: android, performance

I wrote the code to create bitmap from a given byte array. Below is the sample code:

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(imgData));
```

However, it takes around 15-20 ms. Similarly, there might be other operation which can consume time in an android application. In adb logcat, I see GC_ALLOC_FREE....paused 14ms, growing heap size etc etc.

My question: Is there a way to pre-allocate memory in android applications so it can avoid GC being invoked so many time? I searched online and I got to know that usually game apps do it for performance optimization, however, could't find an example on how to do it.

EDIT:
As per the below suggestion, I have 'bm' as the member variable and create ByteBuffer object.

```
Bitmap bm = bm.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(<length>);
```

Then the below code keep getting invoked over and over again:

```
bitmap.copyPixelFromBuffer(bb.put(data));
```

However, it gave me the same result and I still see GC_FOR_ALLOC freed...paused 15 ms.

Also, the above code of line gets invoked in a listener method and it gets the 'data' as an argument.

Comment: Ummm... just don't let go of the object, so it is not garbage collected, and reuse it instead. Use an object pool if you have a need for an arbitrary number of such objects. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CommonsWare Please see the edited question above.

Comment: Might be worth using the DDMS allocation tracker to see what's being allocated (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/track-memory-allocations.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edited code was actually right, however, I was generating some byte array in other part of my code which was making GC work hard.

@CommansWare: your response pointed me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you create your bitmap using [`BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)? Then it does everything automagically for you.  Also you can check out the extended version of that method that allows you to set the width and height (and other parameters) ahead of time.